# Java just glossing over a decimal place?

Tags: java, netbeans

So I'm trying to do a relatively simple program, but I am running into java's integer limits. The number is 471.5 billion. A friend suggested that I multiply 481.5 by 1000 a couple times in order to output the correct number. When I do this, the output is just 481 times 1000, no matter what I do.

As well, if I multiply by 1000 more than twice, It gives really odd numbers.

Here is the code

```
int debt1 
debt1 = 481.5; 
system.out.println(debt1 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000);
```

Comment: What *really odd numbers* are you getting?

Comment: You'll want to read up on what the data types are. Int can't hold fractions, and all numeric types have maximum values

Comment: -3633715. It runs without issue and no warnings when writing it.

Comment: You might want to consider using BigDecimal.

Comment: Tried that as well as BigInteger. IDE doesn't know what to do with it

Comment: `BigInteger` has to be used in a different way from normal primitives; you can't do `*` or `+` with it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your code even compiles correctly?

Your variable is defined as an **int** but you try to assign a **double** value to it.

If you change your variable type to **double**, it can hold the value 481.5 that you try to assign to it.

But in any case, if you want to deal with REALLY big numbers like 481.500.000.000, you should use **BigInteger**

Notice though that with BigInteger, you won't be able to simply write numbers in your IDE (since no built in java types can handle numbers this big). As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) says, you can create BigIntegers by either using a string representation of a number or by specifying the number in a couple more ways.

For a simple example take a look at this:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger debt = new BigInteger("481500000000");
        debt = debt.add(new BigInteger("12312"));
        System.out.println(debt.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried BigInteger, my IDE doesn't seem to know what to do with it. Is it not included standard in most IDE's?

Comment: Also changing to double results in output (no multiplication) being 481.0

Comment: You need to import the class:
import java.math.BigInteger;